# how to set state for input element created dynamically

Tags: reactjs

I'm creating an input element using document.createElement and setting the attribute. i would like to have an onchange event which will update the state.
how can i proceed? following is my code

```
addoffers = () => {

        var input = document.createElement("input");
        input.setAttribute('name', 'whatweoffer'.concat(Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1)));
        input.setAttribute('class','form-control mb-3');
        input.setAttribute('placeholder','what we offer');
        input.onchange =  this.handleChange;
        var parent = document.getElementById("offerinput");
        parent.appendChild(input);


    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        console.log(e.target.value);

    }

<input type="text" className="form-control mb-3" id='whatweoffer'  name='whatweoffer' onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder='what we offer' required />
```

Comment: have you tried with loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
class DynamicInputs {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            inputs : []
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                {
                    this.state.inputs.map(inputValue =>{
                        <input key= {inputValue} type="text" placeholder="what we offer" className="form-control mb-3" name = {`whatweoffer${inputValue}`}  onChange = {this.handleChange} required/>                    })
                }
            </React.Fragment>
        )
    }

    handleChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
        console.log(e.target.value);

    }

    addInput() = () =>{
        let {inputs} = this.state;
        inputs.push((Math.floor((Math.random() * 1000) + 1))
        this.setState({
            inputs
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Although there's accepted answer but I want to give you another approach.
Instead of create `input` dynamically, why don't you just use own component's state to decide if an input is displayed or not, and other attributes are just state values. For example:

```
render() {
  const {
    isInputDisplayed, inputName, inputId, inputClasses, inputPlaceholder,
  } = this.state;
  return (
    { isInputDisplayed && (
      <input type="text" name={inputName} id={inputId} className={inputClasses} placeholder={inputPlaceholder} />
    )}

  );
}
```